# Emacs: getting readable keyboard-macros

Tags: emacs, keyboard, macros, lisp

When using `insert-kbd-macro` to save a named keyboard macro I get "unreadable" Lisp code like

```
(fset 'ppsql
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([134217788 134217765 44 return 44 17 10 return 33 134217765 102 102 backspace 114 111 109 return 17 10 102 111 109 backspace backspace 114 111 return 33] 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

I'd rather have something like the following:

```
(fset 'move-line-down
      [?\C-a ?\C-k delete down ?\C-y return up])
```

IIRC I used the same method to record, name, and insert both keyboard macros: <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, `name-last-kbd-macro`.

Is it possible to get the first macro in a readable format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The keyboard macro functionality in Emacs stands of two modes: `macros` and `kmacros`. The former returns the macro in a way you like—the symbol form—, the latter provides the lambda form. So that, if you call `name-last-kbd-macro` you get a symbol form, if you call `kmacro-name-last-macro`, you get a lambda form.

### Update

As per @marcz observation, in more recent versions of Emacs, `name-last-kbd-macro` is an alias for `kmacro-name-last-macro`, and calling `insert-kbd-macro` will provide the following code:

```lisp
(defalias 'move-line-down
   (kmacro "C-a C-k <down> C-y <return> <up>"))
```

Comment: As far of emacs 29 all answers are no more valid. `name-last-kbd-macro` is now a function alias to `kmacro-name-last-macro`. Which now use `kmacro` to create a macro from a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that!

So the **naming** of the macro determines the format when **inserting**?

I've conducted some more experiments and noticed that `M-x insert-kbd-macro RET RET` would give me the "symbol-form".

Whereas `M-x insert-kbd-macro RET pp2sql RET` gives the "labmda-form" (after naming with `name-last-kbd-macro`).

Now I realize that I've all the way used `name-last-kbd-macro` in my earlier experiments...?

Comment: When you check the function definition of `kmacro-name-last-macro` (`C-h f kmacro-name-last-macro`), you will see in the last line that it calls `kmacro-lambda-form` on the macro--that's why you get the lambda form.

(Next time better edit your question then post a new answer.)

Answer (score -3):

I've never seen the first form.  The second form is what I'm used to.  Did you try re-recording the first macro to see what happens if you're sure you record, then name, then insert?

The other thing to try is "C-X (", which invokes kmacro-start-macro and "C-X )" kmacro-end-macro, rather than F3/F4,which are doing something extraneous about keeping a counter.  Maybe the simpler keyboard macro command will work more straightforwardly.